# Disable user controls in an Android VideoView object

Tags: android, controls, android-videoview

I'm working on an app that plays a video. I cannot find a way to disable the user video controls (Play, pause, go to 1:23, etc...)

How do I remove the user controls from that object? Ideally the bottom bar of controls will not even show up.

Answer (score 2):

VideoView doesn't have controls built in so I'm assuming you have a MediaController set up in your code, which has the controls that appear when tapping the screen and then go away. If that's the case you can remove it and your problem should be solved.